# How to track down why my shared web host is losing data bound for mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, logging, shared-hosting, drupal

I use shared web hosting for a couple of Drupal sites, using my hosting provider's MySQL  database server for storage. One of the sites recently sent me a few emails that should have been written to the database, but there was no record of them.

Both yesterday and today I submitted a form on another of the sites that should have written to the database, but it didn't. There are no errors in Drupal's watchdog log though. How do I down the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt,

Have you take a look at the database logs, or can your host look at their mysql logs for you?
i'd start with contacting your hosting provider to see what they can find since their losing data.

if your looking for a new host, i can also offer recommendations.

Comment: I haven't been able to find the MySQL logs, but I just opened a support ticket to get some help tracking them down. Thanks! I'll probably be moving to VPS hosting next, but I'm always interested in hearing recommendations.

Comment: Hi Matt, I have some great VPS hosting cloud services shoot me an email when the time comes for shopping around.